# Android FireStore onSnapShot() vs get()

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was always getting the data with `get()` . Since I had to check the data of the existing document every time I updated the document and then update it, I thought that if I used `onSnapShot()`, I wouldn't have to check the data.
Here is the question.

1. I am curious about how `onSnapShot()` works to receive data in real time.
2. I wonder if there is a difference in speed compared to using `get()`

There was no way for me to find out how it worked.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `get()`, the Firestore SDK makes a request to the server, and then returns the results to your code. Once the response has been given to your code, the SDK's work is done and the connection can be closed or re-used.

When you start an `onSnapshot` listener, the Firestore SDK keeps an open connection to the server - so that the server can inform the client about relevant updates.

There is no performance difference in the SDK for these two operations, and in fact getting the *initial* data for a listener will take the same amount of time as a `get()` call would take. But of course after that initial data, the `onSnapshot` will continue to listen for updates while the `get()` call won't.